# Can't run pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create with PostgreSQL 9.6 on CentOS 7.3

Tags: postgresql, clustering, high-availability, failover

Follow this guide to do PostgreSQL Automatic Failover:

https://dalibo.github.io/PAF/Quick_Start-CentOS-7.html

At this step:

```
pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_srv1 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="srv1" ipaddr="192.168.122.1" login="<username>" port="srv1-c7" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_srv2 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="srv2" ipaddr="192.168.122.1" login="<username>" port="srv2-c7" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_srv3 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="srv3" ipaddr="192.168.122.1" login="<username>" port="srv3-c7" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_srv1 avoids srv1=INFINITY
pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_srv2 avoids srv2=INFINITY
pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_srv3 avoids srv3=INFINITY
```

What I edited:

```
pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_node1 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="node1" ipaddr="192.168.33.1" login="root" port="5432" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_node2 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="node2" ipaddr="192.168.33.1" login="root" port="5432" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_node1 avoids node1=INFINITY
pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_node2 avoids node2=INFINITY
```

Got error:

```
[root@node1 ~]# pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_node1 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="node1" ipaddr="192.168.33.1" login="root" port="5432" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
Error: Agent 'fence_virsh' not found, use --force to override
[root@node1 ~]# pcs -f cluster1.xml stonith create fence_vm_node2 fence_virsh pcmk_host_check="static-list" pcmk_host_list="node2" ipaddr="192.168.33.1" login="root" port="5432" action="off" identity_file="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
Error: Agent 'fence_virsh' not found, use --force to override
[root@node1 ~]# pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_node1 avoids node1=INFINITY
Error: Resource 'fence_vm_node1' does not exist
[root@node1 ~]# pcs -f cluster1.xml constraint location fence_vm_node2 avoids node2=INFINITY
Error: Resource 'fence_vm_node2' does not exist
```

There is not this IP: `192.168.33.1`, but exist `192.168.33.111`.

I think the `port` means PostgreSQL's port, changed it to `5432`. Maybe not that meaning. So what's the right meaning?

Where was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the `fence-agents` package? That would provide you with the `fence_virsh` binary that `pcs` is complaining isn't there.

Comment: After I install it again `yum install -y fence-agents-virsh`, it seems good. Strange. Thank you.